# Position indicator of a stream, using fwrite

Tags: c, linux

If I am writing in a loop to a a particular file, i.e., stream using fwrite, will the stream indicator be moved forward after each write, so that there are no overwrites?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Every time you call fwrite, the position is advanced. If you for some reason wanted to overwrite, you'd have to use fseek.

Comment: @Duck Right, though then the solution would only work on Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it will.

[fwrite - C++ reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fwrite/)